# convert posixct in R to time in matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I need some help to understand what as.numeric is doing to a POSIxct in R. The reason is that I'm trying to convert some R code to matlab and my conversions don't add up. For example:

This is the R code

```
> time <- as.POSIXct('2009-01-01 23:00')
> 
> as.numeric(time)/86400 + 2440587.5
[1] 2454833
```

and this is the matlab code

```
time = '2009-01-01 23:00';
datenum(time)/86400 + 2440587.5

ans =

   2.4406e+06
```

Why are these not equal and what do I need to do to make my matlab 'time' equal to that in R?

Note that the R package states:
Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC timezone) as a numeric vector, and Julian Day is the number of days since January 1, 4713 BCE at noon UTC, so the Julian Day is calculated as numeric(POSIXct)+2440587.5 days.

Also, what is the value returned from as.numeric(time)?

Comment: From TFM (Matlab): _"The `datenum` function creates a numeric array that represents each point in time as the number of days from `January 0, 0000`. The numeric values also can represent elapsed time in units of days. However, the best way to represent points in time is by using the `datetime` data type."_. The origin of time for the `POSIXct` class, `1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC`.

Comment: So, how would I convert one from the other?

Comment: It would appear you should be able to just use `datetime` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html (read the whole page it has examples)